# Php list files in directory with option to delete

Tags: php, delete-file

I have download-ui.php which has this code which excludes some and lists all the other files in a directory, then sorts them and gives each a checkbox.

```
<?php
    $files = array();
    $dir = opendir('.');
    while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "download-ui.php") and ($file != "error_log") and ($file != "favicon.ico")) {
                $files[] = $file; 
        }   
    }

    natcasesort($files);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo '<li class="browse-file">
            <div class="select-all-col"><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$file.'"/></div>
            <div class="file-name-col"><a href="download-ui.php?name='.$folderName."/".$file.'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$file.'</a></div>
            <br />
        </li>';
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to work out how to then get the checkbox values so that these files if checked can be deleted using `unlink()`.

I know I need a form, but need an assist with syntax and capturing the values for the form, this is what I have so far.

```
<form id="delete" action="delete.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" form="delete" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$file.'"/>
</form>
```

Then for delete.php I have

```
<?php?
    foreach ($_post['select[]'] as $file) {
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file); 
        }
        elseif(is_dir($file)) {
            rmdir($file);
        }
    }
    echo "Files deleted successfully.";
?>
```

I think my problem is the input `<input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$file.'"/>`

The error I'm getting with this latest effort is `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in delete.php

Comment: any explanation for the -1 ? Can't fix things if I don't know what the problem is

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted you, but it could be because you didn't state what the problem is that you are having.

Comment: Also, have you checked the php logs to see what errors show up there?

Comment: The problem I'm having is the files are not getting deleted, the error I'm getting is PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in delete.php ... different from before when my submit wasn't fixed, question edited since then

Comment: might be I need to specify the path somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop through each item of $_POST['select'], so your foreach should say:

```
foreach ($_POST['select'] as $file) {

}
```

Notice that POST is capitalized and select has no array brackets.

Comment: no luck with that, got the same error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in delete.php. I'm wondering if it's my form thats the problem